# Invalid column name 'Sales Quarter' Errror Message

Tags: sql-server

I am working on the SQL below.

My objective is to:

1) Concatenate FirstName and LastName and place them as a column named Employee Name.

2) Extract only the year from the InvoiceDate column.

3) Determine the Quarters from the InvoiceDate and place them into a column called Sales Quarter.

4) Determine the Max, Count, and Sum and place them into columns called Highest Price, Number of Sales, and Total Sales.

5) Group by Year and Sales Quarter.

6) Order by Employee Name, Year, and Sales Quarter.

When executing the code below I get the following message.

> "Invalid column name "Sales Quarter".

I have no idea what I am doing wrong...any advice would be most helpful.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(E.FirstName,' ', E.LastName) AS "Employee Name"
    , YEAR(I.InvoiceDate) AS "Fiscal Year"
    , CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'First'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Second'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Third'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Fourth'
        END "Sales Quarter"
    , MAX(I.Total) AS "Highest Price"
    , COUNT(*) AS "Number of Sales"
    , SUM(IL.UnitPrice) AS "Total Sales"

FROM Employee E
LEFT JOIN Customer C
    ON E.EmployeeId = C.SupportRepId
JOIN Invoice I
    ON C.CustomerId = I.CustomerId
JOIN InvoiceLine IL
    ON I.InvoiceId = IL.InvoiceId 

WHERE I.InvoiceDate  BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2012-06-30'

GROUP BY YEAR(I.InvoiceDate), "Sales Quarter"
ORDER BY CONCAT(E.FirstName,' ', E.LastName), YEAR(I.InvoiceDate), "Sales Quarter"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - in group by clause alias is not recognized

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(E.FirstName,' ', E.LastName) AS "Employee Name"
    , YEAR(I.InvoiceDate) AS "Fiscal Year"
    , CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'First'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Second'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Third'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Fourth'
        END "Sales Quarter"
    , MAX(I.Total) AS "Highest Price"
    , COUNT(*) AS "Number of Sales"
    , SUM(IL.UnitPrice) AS "Total Sales"

FROM Employee E
LEFT JOIN Customer C
    ON E.EmployeeId = C.SupportRepId
JOIN Invoice I
    ON C.CustomerId = I.CustomerId
JOIN InvoiceLine IL
    ON I.InvoiceId = IL.InvoiceId 

WHERE I.InvoiceDate  BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2012-06-30'

GROUP BY YEAR(I.InvoiceDate), CONCAT(E.FirstName,' ', E.LastName),DATEPART ( qq,I.InvoiceDate )  ,CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'First'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Second'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Third'
        WHEN MONTH(I.InvoiceDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Fourth'
        END
ORDER BY CONCAT(E.FirstName,' ', E.LastName), YEAR(I.InvoiceDate), DATEPART ( qq,I.InvoiceDate )
```

Comment: I forgot to add one objective which was to list 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth' in that order instead of alphabetical order? I have no idea how to execute that?

Comment: Hmm, I just ran it and it renders the following error message: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'Employee.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'Employee.LastName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @tonykaroshi, you can check now - you need to add CONCAT(E.FirstName,' ', E.LastName) in group by clause also

Comment: I'm still getting error messages: Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Column "Invoice.InvoiceDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.